# Displaying images using 2 different file inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to preview images selected using different `input type file`. My js fiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ugPDx/764/

For now I can display only 1 image at a time. When I browse for the second one, the image gets overwritten. I have to use two input tags as they are different.

Please help!

Comment: You're using the same function name twice, `readURL`, change it and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Change Your Jsp to :   
 <div>
  <input id="asd1" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
 </div>
<div>
<input id="asd2" type='file' onchange="readURL1(this);" />
 <img id="blahblah" src="#" alt="your image1" />
</div>
```

Change your JavaScript to:

```
        var img1 =document.getElementById("asd1");
    var img2 = document.getElementById("asd2");
    function readURL(img1) {
        if (img1.files && img1.files[0]) {
            var reader1 = new FileReader();

            reader1.onload = function (e) {
                alert(e.target.result);
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result).width(150).height(200);
            };

            reader1.readAsDataURL(img1.files[0]);
        }
    }

    function readURL1(img2) {
        if (img2.files && img2.files[0]) {
            var reader2 = new FileReader();

            reader2.onload = function (e1) {
                alert(e1.target.result);
                $('#blahblah').attr('src', e1.target.result).width(150).height(200);
            };
            reader2.readAsDataURL(img2.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

Your JavaScript Functions have same names